# Ignoring ? in a regex in String replaceFirst method

Tags: java, string

I have below program:

```
String one = "Hello I am IN (?)";
String two = one.replaceFirst(" IN (?)", " IN ('one','two')");
System.out.println(two);
```

The output is:

```
Hello I am IN ('one','two')(?)
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
Hello I am IN ('one','two')
```

What is the issue? It has to do with `replaceFirst` method having first argument as a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first parameter of `replaceFirst()` is a regex, you need to escape the `(?)` as `(?)` has a special meaning in regex(read meta character).

```
String two = one.replaceFirst(" IN \\(\\?\\)", " IN ('one','two')");
```

To avoid escaping, you can use the `replace()` method, which doesn't take a regex as the replace string.

```
String two = one.replace(" IN (?)", " IN ('one','two')");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression as its first argument. `(` and `)` are meta characters used to denote capturing groups, `?` being the non-greedy quantifier

You can either escape meta characters

```
String two = one.replaceFirst(" IN \\(\\?\\)", " IN ('one','two')");
```

or (better) using the `replace` method as mentioned by @RJ

```
String two = one.replace(" IN (?)", " IN ('one','two')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
String one = "Hello I am IN (?)";
String two = one.replaceFirst(" IN \\(\\?\\)", " IN ('one','two')");
System.out.println(two);
```